# Django: 400 Error with Debug=False and ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run a relatively simple Django server on Python 3.5.3 on an Ubuntu DigitalOcean droplet. I'm using a Gunicorn server with nginx.

The server runs fine when `DEBUG=True` in **settings.py**. But when I set it to **False**, I get a *400 error* when trying to visit the page. I tried setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, but I still get the same error.

I've looked on a lot of forums and many questions on SO but none of the solutions have worked.

**EDIT**

Gunicorn logs from startup:

```
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f9ac58d3d90>
  worker_class: sync
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f9ac58c8f28>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  statsd_host: None
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  default_proc_name: KivaWebsite.wsgi
  capture_output: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  pythonpath: None
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f9ac58c8d90>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f9ac58d32f0>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f9ac58d37b8>
  ca_certs: None
  syslog_prefix: None
  django_settings: None
  sendfile: None
  group: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f9ac58c8a60>
  accesslog: None
  statsd_prefix: 
  threads: 1
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  graceful_timeout: 30
  cert_reqs: 0
  proc_name: None
  spew: False
  loglevel: DEBUG
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f9ac58d3950>
  timeout: 30
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f9ac58d3f28>
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  max_requests: 0
  keepalive: 2
  preload_app: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  syslog_facility: user
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f9ac58d3a60>
  certfile: None
  bind: ['unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock']
  ssl_version: 3
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: logs2.log
  logconfig: None
  umask: 0
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  workers: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  chdir: /home/thomas/KivaWebsite
  paste: None
  keyfile: None
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f9ac58c8bf8>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f9ac58d3158>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f9ac58d3488>
  backlog: 2048
  syslog: False
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f9ac58d3620>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f9ac58d3bf8>
  daemon: False
  user: 0
  proxy_protocol: False
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl'}
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock (27160)
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27163] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27163
[2016-09-13 00:02:01 +0000] [27160] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2016-09-13 00:02:25 +0000] [27163] [DEBUG] GET /
```

**EDIT**

Nginx logs show an error:

```
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock:/", host: "104.131.153.181"
2016/09/12 12:06:47 [crit] 22081#22081: *96 connect() to unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

However, I have checked and the file definitely exists. This is my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 104.131.153.181;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/thomas/KivaWebsite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: did you try looking in the server logs? 400 indicates perhaps a malformed request or other client error

Comment: my (random) guess is that nginx never expected SSL back from the wsgi_pass.  I never use gunicorn but the last line (`[DEBUG] GET /`) suggests that the request reached gunicorn.  You also have the nginx logs in /var/log/nginx

Comment: Did you alias the nginx config with absolute paths? (ie: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`) It doesn't work if the alias was done with a relative path (for some reason). Try setting this on `location /` right before the `proxy_pass` line instead of your current lines: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_redirect off;
include uwsgi_params;`

Comment: @Av4t4r Thank you so much! The change in my config file worked! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TheRuler Done :). I strongly suggest, however, that you change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to only accept connections from localhost and the current internal network (in the case of DigitalOcean, I believe it should only be set to localhost) for security reasons

Comment: @Av4t4r Good idea, thanks for reminding me to change that back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the config in nginx has the proper alias using absolute paths (ie: `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`) 
It doesn't work if the alias was done with a relative path for whatever reason.

This are the appropriate settings for nginx at the `location / {}` section:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_redirect off;
include uwsgi_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/thomas/KivaWebsite/KivaWebsite.sock;
```