# Django DEBUG=False resulting in 400 error for all requests

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, uwsgi

I'm running my Django app in a Docker container with nginx as the webserver, and uWSGI as the app server.  Everything is deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  When I set `DEBUG=False`, all the requests result in `Bad Request (400)`.  I have tried both `ALLOWED_HOSTS='*'` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`, and I still get the same error.  I verified the request is coming to uWSGI by checking the logs.  The uWSGI logs have this:

```
[pid: 33|app: 0|req: 4/4] 172.17.0.1 () {46 vars in 855 bytes} [Tue Aug  1 02:54:17 2017] GET / => generated 26 bytes in 26 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 1 headers in 53 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

I've tried a bunch of answers, but no luck.  I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461321/2233706), but I still get the same error.  Is there anything else that could cause this?

This question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875789/django-gives-bad-request-400-when-debug-false), because, as I mentioned, setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to wildcard did not work for me.  From the same question, I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38679144/2233706), and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can the admins/someone please remove the tag that this is a duplicate? I noted that I had tried out the solution specified in the supposed duplicate question when I created the question and only clarified it when prompted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that my URL has an underscore, and Django does not allow underscores anywhere in the URL.  I had `www._test_.example.com`.  `www._test.example.com` and `www.a_test.example.com` don't work either.  [Underscores should be valid characters in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it).

Comment: I have lots of endpoints served by Django with underscores in them.